# SQL Server 2008 cross server queries 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to create reports on SSRS 2008 from data available on SQL Server 2000, now; the database on SQL2000 is preferably not touched so I am avoiding adding stored procedures, views, indexes etc..

What would be the right solution?

What I would be needing is a place where I can put stored procedures, views etc so I can do reports.

Thanks.

Comment: So I can create stored procedures and views on the 2008 server and use the 2000 server's data?

Comment: So you are basically suggesting to create a database on SQL2008 which will be only used to hold stored procedures and views and do all of the reporting on those views/sp, right?

Answer (score 0):

create an ssis package / dataflowtask, copy your data from one source (sql 2000 - sql 2008r2)
create a reporting database, move your data to this database and make your reports on this database